# hangman in python using only while loops

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to create a hangman game using only while loops:

I'm trying to display the dashes of a secret word or if the letter has been guessed and is in variable correct letters display the correct letters in the right place and the rest will be dashes - all using a while loop.

However if the string correct letters is empty as it will be at the start of the game just display the dashes.

I'm not allowed to use for loops or in, just while loops and currently stuck with the following error:

```
tmp_letter = p_correct_letters[count]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

MY CODE:

```
from hangman_lib import HANGMAN
import hangman_lib
import random


words = ["ant","baboon","zebra"]

def main():
    game_over = False
    correct_letters = ""
    incorrect_letters = ""

    secret_word = get_word()
    print("Welcome to Hangman!")
    print(secret_word) # For testing purposes only

    while not game_over:
        display_board(secret_word, correct_letters, incorrect_letters)

        guess = get_guess(correct_letters + incorrect_letters)

        if found_letter(guess, secret_word):
            correct_letters = correct_letters + guess
        else:
            incorrect_letters = incorrect_letters + guess

        game_over = has_won(secret_word, correct_letters)

        if not game_over:
            game_over = has_lost(incorrect_letters)

        if game_over:
            display_board(secret_word, correct_letters, incorrect_letters)


''' Non temlate Code starts here '''

# Function returns random word from list of words
def get_word():
    return random.choice(words)

def display_board(p_secret_word, p_correct_letters, p_incorrect_letters):
    print(HANGMAN[len(p_incorrect_letters)])
    print("\n")

    print ("Guess a letter... ")

    word_length = len(p_secret_word)
    underscore = "_ "
    to_display = ""

    display_underscore = underscore * word_length
    print(display_underscore)

    print("\n")
    print("Incorrect letters:", p_incorrect_letters)

    index = 0
    current_letter =""
    tmp_letter =""
    correct_length = len(p_correct_letters)


    while index < word_length:
        current_letter = p_secret_word[index]
        count = 0

        while count < correct_length:
            tmp_letter = p_correct_letters[count]

            if current_letter == tmp_letter:
                to_display = to_display[count] + current_letter + " "
            else:
                to_display = underscore + " "

        count = count + 1

    index = index + 1

    print(to_display, end = "")

    # return current print statement 

    main()
```

Comment: Your. Indentation. Has. Gone. __Wild__.

Comment: What's more, you can't 'return current print statement'.

Comment: I'd write my own function which emulates `for` in terms of `while`, then use that. Really, disallowing `for` is pretty useless for anything but making you cognizant of how useful `for` is.

Comment: You could write your solution using for loops and then mechanically replace each for loop by a while loop

Answer (score 0):

In python, there are two primary uses of `in`, to iterate through iterables, and to determine membership in a list or set.

The first use case (iteration) can be substituted for with another loop structure, like `while`, which you've done.

The second use case (membership testing) can be done either with nested loops or using one of the builtin membership methods on `sets` and `lists`.

For example, in your `display_board` function, the bottom `while` loop looks like it's trying to display the secret word, with correct guesses printing the letter, and unguessed letters printed with underscores.  The error you're getting is a result of iterating past the end of the `correct_letters` list.

To do this, you need to:

1. Loop through each letter in the secret word.
2. For each letter in the secret word, test if that letter is one of the correct guesses. If it is a correct guess, display the letter, if not, display an underscore.

The first step can be accomplished with a `while` loop.

```
i = 0
while i < len(word):
   # do stuff
   i += 1
```

The second step could be accomplished a number of ways, but I think the simplest and most straightforward way is with one of the built-in membership testing methods, like `list.count` (or possibly `list.index`) and `set.intersection`.

```
word = 'magic'
correct_letters = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

while i < len(word):
    letter = word[i]

    if correct_letters.intersection(letter)
        print (letter)
    else:
        print ('_')

    i += 1
```

I think `sets` work better here, but you could uses `lists`, too, if maintaining the order of the guessed letters is important:

```
correct_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']

if correct_letters.count(letter)
    print (letter)
else:
    print ('_')
```

Comment: indentation is crazy! i'm pasting my code and have to manual add in extra spaces  so it show up on here. ;(

Comment: I've updated my code it now prints nothing , even when i add a,e,i,o,u to the list of correct letters :(

Comment: What did you update on your code?  Did you try any of the suggestions I offered?  It looks like you're still using a string to store the correct letters, instead of a set.  And you're still iterating through the correct letters incorrectly (iterating past the end).

Comment: i've just updated, sorry posted the comments before id finished editing the code

Comment: In each iteration, you should probably do `to_display += ` instead of redefining it each time.

Comment: will be using a list of strings

Comment: correct letters has to be a string for this exercise unfortunately.

Comment: I still need to process the last element of the list and update which is why I haven't used length-1. Once i go past the last element my code wont run anyway.